# Resizing mapbox mapview messes up scale - Android

Tags: android, mapbox

How do I properly resize a mapbox mapview if the height dynamically changes?

Comment: Hey Tim, I'll gladly answer this one if you still need help. Could you explain to me what you mean by height dynamically changes? Even better, if you could share with me the code in question I can get a better grasp on what your trying to accomplish.